# Visual Studio 2010: Editor Slow -> SmartTags Exceptions?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, exception, editor, slowdown

sometimes the VS2010 Editor is incredibly slow (1 char/sec). But at first the same editor window, same document, performs well.

Editor: Html with Razor

I attached another VS instance to slow instance and got this multiple times in the Debug Output window:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.SmartTags.dll
```

How can I solve this?

Edit:
Additional information: if I close the tab and reopen the document it performs well but only for some time.

Comment: I am sure you've been through this but have you tried removing all extensions and/or reinstalling?

Comment: Or check if the extensions need updates, they might have fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I manage to solve this by following the steps in [this blog](http://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/218-visual-studio--resharper-performance-tips/).

I didn't have to do all of the steps. The step that "saved" me was

> **Disable "Rich client visual experience"** in the "Options -
>   Environment". Here's how that settings page should look:[screenshot](http://d.pr/i/733e)

I hope this will solve your problem.